# How can we make popover appear in the list items of the navbar in twitter bootstrap css?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

```
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top my-header" > 

    <div class="navbar-header">

  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only "> Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar "></span>
    <span class="icon-bar "></span>
    <span class="icon-bar "></span>
   </button>
    <ul class ="nav navbar-nav>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="content" role="button" data-original-title="Title">Hover to toggle popover</a></li>
     </ul>
      </div>
      </nav>
```

althought i have keep the data-toggle="popover"  it is not appearing in the link of navbar in of the twitter bootstrap.

Comment: Are you including the tooltip plugin as mentioned in the documentation? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-examples

Comment: Have you read: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers ?
By the code you're giving us here I can see you're missing atleast data-placement attribute from the link.

Comment: i have included bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js but still its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in, meaning that you must initialize them yourself:

```
$('body').popover({
        selector: 'a[data-toggle=popover]',
        container: 'body'
    }).tooltip({
        selector: "a[data-toggle=tooltip]",
        container: 'body'
});
```

Comment: In which section of bootstrap should this be initialized.

Comment: This needs to be added to your custom Javascript code (that comes after Bootstrap JS imports of course)

Answer (score 0):

try this one... just customize it for better result

http://www.bootply.com/HC0GXUzXnE

just add like this..

```
$('#showMe').popover('show')
```